# как сделать, чтоб второй аргумент функции по умолчанию был равен первому в PHP

Tags: php

как сделать, чтоб второй аргумент функции по умолчанию был равен первому в PHP

Comment: В функции второму аргументу присвойте значение первого

Comment: так не пойдет. так не получается.

Comment: Покажите код и что вы хотите в итоге

Comment: уже получилось, я написал ниже

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function f($n1, $n2=null) {
    if ($n2 == null) {
        $n2 = $n1;
    }
}
```

Comment: `$n2 = $n2 ?? $n1` в последних версиях

Comment: да получилось только там надо осатвить этот null, а то ошибку дает.

Comment: @teran, `$n2 ??= $n1` в php7.4